# () as empty constraint

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

how can one represent the empty constraint ?

for the following file

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind(Type, Constraint)

type Empty = (() :: Type -> Constraint)

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

ghc 8.2.2 answers

```
constraint.hs:6:15: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘()’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘(() :: Type -> Constraint)’
      In the type declaration for ‘Empty’
  |
6 | type Empty = (() :: Type -> Constraint)
  |
```

what do i miss ?

i know about the following solution

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Empty x
instance Empty x
```

but i want to know why () does not work

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `()` has kind `*` or `Constraint`, depending on context, never `a -> Constraint`. Similarly `(,)` has kind `* -> * -> *` or `Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint`, depending on context.
>
> — [Simon Peyton-Jones](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2011-December/021355.html)

It’s just that `()` is only overloaded for whether it’s a type or a constraint. That is, you’d write `() => a`, not `(() a) => a`. So I think this:

```
class Empty x
instance Empty x
```

Is the correct solution here. (And perhaps something like that should be in `base`.)

Comment: the quote from and link to the mailing list discussion about the topic helped me

Comment: now i guess my mistake was the confusion between 'constraint' and 'class'

Answer (score 3):

`()` has kind `Constraint` and is not meant to be applied to a `Type`.

Answer (score 3):

[Jon Purdy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261741/1477667) is correct. If you want one thing you can slap in regardless of arity (except in an instance head or type family LHS), you're going to need to use some boilerplate:

```
{-# language PolyKinds, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances,
    MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint)

class Unit1 a
instance Unit1 a
class Unit2 a b
instance Unit2 a b
...

type family Unit :: k
type instance Unit = (() :: Constraint)
type instance Unit = Unit1
type instance Unit = Unit2
...
```

Then

```
Prelude K> type Empty = (Unit :: Type -> Constraint)
Prelude K> :kind! Empty
Empty :: * -> Constraint
= Unit1
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these work fine, depending on what you want:

```
type Empty = (() :: Constraint)
type ConstEmpty x = (() :: Constraint)
```

Comment: `ConstEmpty` is actually completely useless.

Comment: @dfeuer I included it because the question explicitly asks for something of kind `* -> Constraint`. Why do you say it's useless? It looks approximately as useful to me as the `class Empty x; instance Empty x` solution mentioned in other answers to which you did not object; the only thing you can't do with it compared to that is partially apply it.

Comment: Partially applying it is indeed its entire purpose. That makes it *useful*. For example, if a class has an associated type `type Constr a :: * -> Constraint`, then `type Constr A = Empty` is a perfectly good instantiation. `ConstEmpty`, on the other hand, can only be used fully applied, where the entire application could be written `()`.